# How to debug how ESLint merges configs?

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslintrc

ESLint can merge multiple configs together through the `extends` key, but it's never clear what actually happens under the hood and why some rules can randomly stop working.

The ESLint documentation is very light on how ESLint actually merges these configs, but are there some other resources that explain this? Or better yet - some sort of tool that outputs the finalized config once everything is merged?

Comment: You could try the `--print-config` flag via the CLI tool: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/command-line-interface

Comment: @lux Thanks, this is useful. It would be great if one could prevent it from destructuring all of the extended configs tho, because it outputs them as a large collection of rules that's difficult to analyze.